# jquery not working on iphone safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

I have a problem with the wordpress plugin i wrote. All the jquery items are not working on the iphone browser. On all other devices there is no issue.

First i toggle the visibility of a div with a check box. I tried those 2 methods but none of them works on safari mobile.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#check1').click(function(){
        jQuery('#div1').toggle(this.checked);
    });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#check2').on('click touchstart', (function(event){
        jQuery('#div2').toggle(this.checked);
    }));

});
```

I also added cursor:pointer; to the checkbox css, but also it doesn't work.

Also the datepicker

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#startDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

and also the form validation are not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".cc_form").validate({
        rules: {
            ID_cat: "required",
            eis: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            ID_cat: "<b id='error'>Error</b>",
            reisepreis: {
                required: "<b id='error'>Error</b>",
                number: "<b id='error'>Error</b>"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone now what to do?

thanks